Simulated random walk for forecasting
I have made an exercise where I simulate the outcomes for the change in the exchange rate. The simulated outcomes are supposed to mimic a random walk and are generated with the mean and variance identical to the mean and variance of the realized change during a particular sample period.
I have then used the forecasts from my economic models (estimated on the true exchange rate data) to compute forecast errors for my models against the randomized outcomes.
I do however find my results peculiar. The mean share of my forecasts that beat the no-change forecast on a direction accuracy measure is 60 %. As the outcomes are simulated I was expecting a mean very close to 50 %. I am trying to come up with an explanation for this. I know that:

73 % of my model forecasts are positive.
57 % of the realized outcomes are positive.
57 % of the simulated outcomes are positive (reasonable, as they have identical mean and variance to the realized outcomes)
I have a total of 14 million simulated forecast errors.

So I know that if all my forecasts were positive, I would beat the no-change forecast in 57 % of the cases. However, the positive 57 % of the simulated outcomes should not match up with the 73 % of the positive forecasts. Rather, this should happen in 50 % of those cases. And also in 50 % of the cases for the negative forecasts.
Then how on earth do I explain that even though the outcomes are simulated, I beat the no-change forecast in 60 % of the cases on the direction of change statistic?
The random numbers was generated in R.
Edit: My reasoning is likely wrong. 73 % positive will at least beat the no-change in 30  % of the positive cases, because this is the minimum overlapping share of 73 and 57. Hmm. I guess this boils down to an overlapping sets problem. The least possible overlap should be 30 % and the maximum possible should be 84 %. Correct? Then a mean of 57 should be expected?
Edit 2: Take the EUR/USD exchange rate from 2015-2020. This makes 60 months of one period exchange rate changes that are either positive or negative. In the data, 57 % of the these are positive. I have used a model to forecast these changes. I then replace all the 60 one period changes with randomized values that have the same mean and variance as the actual data. My forecasts are then compared to these random values. For example, my model forecasts a positive change from 2015M3 to 2015M4. The random value happens to be negative. Then I will lose against the no-change (zero) forecast because my forecast error is larger. And with the same reasoning, every time I correctly predict the direction of change (positive or negative) I will beat the no-change forecast.

Sorry, can you please add a bit more details on your setup (what is "positive", how are "wins" defined, what is measured for real outcomes and what for simulated, etc.)? IIUC, you simulate random walk with some parameters, and use your model to predict it, is it correct? If so, what do 57% and 73% refer to?

Sorry if unclear. Ill try to rephrase.

Do I understand correctly, that you have your model, that gives approximately 44 ($0.73 \cdot 60$) "positive" and 16 "negative", your simulation that gives approximately 34 "positive" and 26 "negative" results, and your model agrees with simulation on approximately 36 cases?

Yes, that is correct, on average after repeating the exercise more than a million times. For each seed of simulated outcomes the agreement can range from anything between 18 (0.360) and 50 (0.8460) cases.
